# what's the best way to add a line break before and after div?

Tags: html, line-breaks

Someone shows me a html to use div tag to show some text with background image included

```
<div class='main'>
   <div class='img1'>
      SOME TITLE TEXT
   </div>  
</div>";
<div class='img2'>"
  SOME DESCRIPTION TEXT HERE
</div>"
```

Here the class img1 and img2 include two background images and the corresponding div for img2 will be shown next to img1 (without gap). I need to repeat the whole pattern couple times to show something with different content but same format.

```
<!-- GROUP 1 -->  
<div class='main'>
   <div class='img1'>
      SOME TITLE TEXT 1
   </div>  
</div>";
<div class='img2'>"
  SOME DESCRIPTION TEXT HERE 1
</div>"
<!-- GROUP 2 -->  
<div class='main'>
   <div class='img1'>
      SOME TITLE TEXT 2
   </div>  
</div>";
<div class='img2'>"
  SOME DESCRIPTION TEXT HERE 2
</div>"
```

But I found that there is no separation between any two groups as shown above. Frankly, I really have no experience in html, I just copy the code from someone else. But after searching online, I find the 
 command, I try to add that tag in between the groups but it seems that the break is too much than I expect. Is there any other way to insert separation with smaller gap?

Comment: *"Frankly, I really have no experience in html, I just copy the code from someone else."* Wow, that's great! What an ingenious way of creating wonderful HTML pages! (/sarcasm). Seriously, learn HTML. It's not very hard. Once you learned the semantics it's super easy. Styling with CSS is also not that hard. But it's better to learn those so you can create your pages fast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can give `margin` from `top` and `bottom` like this:

```
margin: 10px 0;
```

Above will apply `10px` margin from top and bottom. You can also use individual properties such as `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`.

Comment: This will probably result in [collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins). However, the result might still be something the OP wants to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

one way is to use css to style your elements.

```
<style>
.main
{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
</style>
```

you can alter as needed..not sure what div's you want to seperate

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 main ways to add line breaks: through line break `<br>` tags and through paragraph tags `<p>`. So all you have to do is to put those tags in between your  tags.

Comment: There is _one_ semantic correct way to add a line-break, `<br>`. `<p>` does the same job, but has another semantic, since it introduces a paragraph. A paragraph can contain line-breaks, but the other way round is simply wrong.

Comment: I try that one but the separation introduced is too much. But thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Add the child divs to span like below

```
<div class="class1" >
   <span class="span1">
         data1 
       <br>
       <span class="span2">
            data2
       </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

css:

```
   .span1{
      display:inline-block;
    }
    .span2{
      display:inline-block;     
    }




    </div>
```