# How to set a line break between span elements

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML table, wich one of the columns will contain a long line of text. But some pieces of this text need to have different font colors, so i divide this text into a series of span elements, so i can format each one accordingly. The problem is that i can make the text wrap inside this cell, its expanding the TD size to fit the elements.

I don't need the text inside each span to break, but when the elements reach the end of the TD element, i want the next span to be arranged in the next line.

Does anyone there know how can i do that?

A example to illustrate:

Source:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
          <span>Sample Text A</span>
          <span>Sample Text B</span>
          <span>Sample Text C</span>
          <span>Sample Text D</span>
          <span>Sample Text E</span>
          <span>Sample Text F</span>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

This is the desired output:

```
This is the limit of the TD element =============>|
Sample Text A Sample Text B Sample Text C 
Sample Text D Sample Text E Sample Text F
```

This is the result i'm getting:

```
This is the limit of the TD element =============>|
Sample Text A Sample Text B Sample Text C Sample Text D Sample Text E Sample Text F
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61071200/6302996

Answer (score 11):

If you make the `span` an `inline-block` you will get the behaviour you want;

```
span
  {display:inline-block}
```

Then set the width of the table cell to `20em` like this;

```
td
  {width:20em; border:1px solid red}
```

(The red border is just so you can see what's going on.)

The screen will look like this;

[image: capture]

If you were to change the width to `15em` like this;

```
td
  {width:15em; border:1px solid red}
```

then the screen would show this;

[image]

FYI here's the HTML I used for the screen captures;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
       <tr>
          <td>
              <span>Sample Text A</span>
              <span>Sample Text B</span>
              <span>Sample Text C</span>
              <span>Sample Text D</span>
              <span>Sample Text E</span>
              <span>Sample Text F</span>
          </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
<html>
```

Comment: This appears to disallow a browser search through the boundary however. Alternative option includes inserting <wbr> element.

Answer (score 1):

You can try either:

```
td {
  word-break:break-all;
}
```

or

```
td {
  word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Then, assigning a width to the `td` as well as setting `table-layout:fixed;` to the table itself should force the words to wrap when they hit the width of the table cell.

[Fiddle #1](http://jsfiddle.net/LJ4Lj/) | [Fiddle #2](http://jsfiddle.net/rcsLs/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `table-layout:fixed` on the `<table>` to force strict width handling, then explicitly set your desired width on the table cell.