# How to insert a line break in span using CSS?

Tags: html, css

[image: Button created using span]

Now I want to break the line on Q1 and move this Q1 next to Summary. Is there a way to do it? Following is the CSS for the button.

```css
span {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 80%;
    line-height: normal;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 2rem;
    border: 1px solid #019ed5;
    border-radius: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Just use <br> tag between them

Comment: Post a complete code example please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61071200/6302996

Comment: .word {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

Answer (score 32):

Try adding:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Note: it may change the behavior a bit.

in the html:

```
<span>JAN-MAR <br /> Q1 Summary</span>
```

You may also use js, for a more dynamic approach:

```
<span class="q-span">JAN-MAR Q1 Summary</span>
```

and you can use jQuery to do it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".q_header").each(function(){
        // Get content
        var 
            content = $(this).text(),
        // get first word
            first_w = content.match(/([\w\-]+)/);

        // replace the first word with first word and break
        var new_cnt = content.replace(first_w[0], first_w[0] + "</br>");

        // add the css to make it inline-block
        $(this).css("display", "inline-block").html(new_cnt);

    });

});
```

Comment: Assuming  the content "JAN-MAR Q1 Summary are being passed as string, and are part of an expression in HTML template, Is there any other way?

Comment: Can depend, is there always going to be a break after the first word? Is it a specific character count that you would like to maintain? We can add some js in there. Applying a one-fits-all solution in CSS depends on if you know the content is always going to follow a specific format. Can you give us some examples of different strings or the pattern that they will have?

Comment: I see what you mean there. So the content will always be on similar format. Line break after JAN-MAR and Q1 Summary will always be on the same line.

Comment: Well, like I said earlier, you can do a javascript hack to automatically add the break after the first word. I'll update the answer to show you how, but it's going away from the original question.

Answer (score 17):

Use

```
display:block;
```

OR
`span` is an inline element, as such styling attributes such as `width` or `margin` don't work. You can fix that by either changing the `span` to a block element (such as `div`), or by using padding instead.

Comment: display: block with the help of bit js hack did the trick. Thanks.